# Add function to a class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a base application that I install to different costumers and to which I add the functionalities that they requests.

Suppouse a single base component that has

```
component-base.html
component-base.ts
```

Now a client asks me to customize it and what I do is duplicate those two files:

```
client-base-component1.html
client-base-component1.ts
```

and in the angualar.jons I tell him

```
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src / components / component-base.html",
              "with": "src / components / component-base-client1.html"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src / components / component-base.ts",
              "with": "src / components / component-base-client1.ts"
            },
```

and then I add the functionality there, but as there are many clients in the end I duplicate a lot of code.

In the html I imagine that it is not possible, but is there a possibility instead of having to duplicate all the functions in component-base-client1.ts, import all the code and just put in the new ones the new functions that I develop (and that only the component-base-client1.html would be used), or even better, to be able to overwrite the functions that are in component-base.ts with those of component-base-client1.ts and in case they are not in component-base-client1.ts component-base.ts are used?

I know it is difficult to explain here what I am looking for, but it would be very useful to better organize my files.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use class inheritance.

```
// Your base component
export class BaseComponent 
    public Function1(): void {
    }
}

// Your client component extending you BaseComponent (this is the inheritance)
export ClientComponent extends BaseComponent {

    // You can override BaseComponent Function1()
    public Function1(): void {
        // You can still call base Function1 on your overrided Function1
        super.Function1();
    }

    // You can add client specific functions
    public ClientSpecificFunction(): void {
    }
}
```

If your BaseComponent injects services, you have to inject them in the inheriting class constructor:

```
export class BaseComponent 

    // Your base component constructor
    constructor(public router: Router) {
    }
}

export ClientComponent extends BaseComponent {

    constructor(public router: Router) {
        super(router);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's looks exactly what I need, but I have a problem. I import BaseComponent  in app.module and in app.routes, and if I now use ClientComponent then I need to duplicate these for each client.... I need app.module.costumer and app.routes.costumer and replace it in angular.json or is other way?

Comment: You can import `app.module.costumer` in `app.module` and `app.routes.costumer` in `app.routes` and replaces them in `angular.json` yes. But this is not the only way to do this, it realy depends on you application architecture. Another point is, you component/routes/module files doesn't fit the Angular naming convension, I suggest you to take a look here: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: And don't forget to mark my answere as accepted ;). If you have more specific question about you app architecture, I suggest you to open a new question :).